# how to include smooth transition to the sliding image carousel using the java-script?

Tags: javascript, html

I have made an automatic sliding image carousel in my website with the the HTML, CSS & Java-Script but the transition from one image to another is not good. Please guide me what to add in the Java-Script area to make the transition smooth?

I have tried the below java-script but I also want to add the smooth transition between the images.

```
<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        autoplay: {
        delay: 3000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
        },
        pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
        },
        navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does your carousel use CSS to move the elements? If so you can use CSS transitions to smooth out the effect. See this for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: @AlxTheRed No, it doesn't runs on CSS, CSS is used only to design the images.

Answer (score 0):

Add a by default fade effect:

```
 var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        autoplay: {
        delay: 3000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
        },
        pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
        },
        navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        effect: fade,
        fadeEffect: {
        crossFade: true }
    });
```

More effects and animations for your carousel are provided [here](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#fade-effect).

Comment: it didn't work. If you have any other animations please share.

Comment: Include also the **effect** parameter. Set to it **fade**. I'll modify the above code.

Comment: I have edited as per your theory but the it is not working. Applying this makes the carousel to interfere with each other.